# Devise user profile route in root of site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have user profiles set up using Devise. Currently the route is `site.com/u/username`, however I want the route to be `site.com/username`. Should I just change

```
match 'u/:username' => 'users#show', as: :user, via: :get
```

to

```
match ':username' => 'users#show', as: :user, via: :get
```

or do I need to do something else?

Also, is there any way to ensure that no username conflicts with other routes? For example, if someone has the username `about`, how to I set a separate route for that user (`/u/about`)